# Template argument deduction from function body

Tags: c++, templates, standards, iso

If we've this function template,

```
template<typename T>
void f(T param) {}
```

Then we can call it in the following ways,

```
int i=0;
f<int>(i);//T=int : no need to deduce T
f(i); //T=int : deduced T from the function argument!

//likewise
sample s;
f(s); //T=sample : deduced T from the function argument!
```

Now consider this variant of the above function template,

```
template<typename TArg, typename TBody>
void g(TArg param) 
{
   TBody v=param.member;
}
```

Now, can the compiler deduce the template arguments if we write,

```
sample s;
g(s); //TArg=sample, TBody=int??
```

Suppose `sample` is defined as,

```
struct sample
{
   int member;
};
```

---

There are basically two questions:

- Can the compiler deduce the template arguments in the second example?
- If no, then why? Is there any difficulty? If the Standard doesn't say anything about *"template argument deduction from  function body"*, then is it because the argument(s) cannot be deduced? Or it didn't consider such deduction so as to avoid adding more complexity to the language? Or what?

I would like know your views on such deduction.

---

EDIT:

By the way, the GCC is able to deduce function arguments if we write this code:

```
template<typename T>
void h(T p)
{
        cout << "g() " << p << endl;
        return;
}
template<typename T>
void g(T p)
{
        h(p.member); //if here GCC can deduce T for h(), then why not TBody in the previous example?
        return;
}
```

Working demonstration for this example : http://www.ideone.com/cvXEA

Not working demonstration for the previous example: http://www.ideone.com/UX038

Answer (score 5):

You probably already concluded that the compiler won't deduce `TBody` by examining the type of `sample.member`. This would add yet another level of complexity to the template deduction algorithm.

The template matching algorithm only considers function *signatures*, not their bodies. While not used too often, it's perfectly legal to simply declare a templated function without providing the body:

```
template <typename T> void f(T param);
```

This satisfies the compiler. In order to satisfy the linker, you must of course also define the function body somewhere, and ensure that all required instantiations have been provided. But the function body does **not** necessarily have to be visible to client code of the template function, as long as the required instantiations are available at link time. The body would have to explicitly instantiate the function, eg:

```
template <> void f(int param);
```

But this only partially applies to your questions, because you could imagine a scenario like the following, where a 2nd parameter could be deduced from the a provided default parameter, and which won't compile:

```
template<typename TArg, typename TBody>
void g(TArg param, TBody body = param.member);  // won't deduce TBody from TArg
```

The template matching algorithm considers only the actual type, not any potential nested member types in case of classes or structs. This would have added another level of complexity which apparently was judged to be too complex. Where should the algorithm stop? Are members of members, and so forth, also to be considered?

Also, it's not required because there are other means of achieving the same intention, as shown in the example below.

Nothing prevents you from writing:

```
struct sample
{
   typedef int MemberType;
   MemberType member;
};

template<typename TArg>
void g(TArg param) 
{
   typename TArg::MemberType v = param.member;
}

sample s = { 0 };
g(s);
```

in order to obtain the same effect.

---

Regarding your sample you added after editing: whereas it seems that `h(p.member)` does depend on the member of the struct, and hence the template matching algorithm should fail, it doesn't because you made it a two-step process:

1. Upon seeing `g(s);`, the compiler looks for any function taking an argument of type `sample` (templated or not!). In your case, the best match is `void g(T p)`. **At this point, the compiler has not even looked at the body of `g(T p)` yet!**.
2. Now, the compiler creates a instance of `g(T p)`, specialized for `T: sample`. So when it sees `h(p.member)` it knows that `p.member` is of type `int`, and will try locate a function `h()` taking an argument of type `int`. Your template function `h(T p)` turns out to be the best match.

Note that if you had written (note the **NOT_A_member**):

```
template<typename T>
void g(T p)
{
        h(p.NOT_A_member);
        return;
}
```

then the compiler would still consider `g()` a valid match at stage 1. You then get an error when it turns out that `sample` does not have a member called `NOT_A_member`.

Comment: or `BOOST_AUTO(v, param.member)`

Comment: and if `sample` is third-party code you can't change, you can still make use of `Traits` to get the same effect.  You could then do `Traits<Targ>::MemberType v = param.member;`

Comment: Updated question. But basically, you're assisting the compiler that way. And: if the argument `p` in `g(T p)` did not contain a member called `member`, then you'd receive a compiler error. It would still match `g(T p)`!

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, so? What is the conclusion?

Comment: @Nawaz - what is the question of your updated question? The 2nd example corresponds to your original question, and hence doesn't compile. The first example doesn't require the compiler to deduce TBody when matching `g()`, so it should compile.

Comment: Or do you mean the conclusion regarding your original question? The template matching algorithm, as defined by the standard, considers only the actual type, not any potential member types in case of classes or structs. This would have added another level of complexity which apparently was judged to be too complex (or not needed, because there are other means to achieve the same result).

Comment: @Daniel: *"not any potential member types in case of classes or structs"*.. then how does it deduce the template argument in the edited part of my post?  `h(p.member)` does depend on the member of the struct!

Comment: @Daniel: Whatever you said, can be said for `TBody` deduction also. I don't see any difficulty. Also, you seem to answer what is in the Standard, while I also want to understand if Standard doesn't have something, then what is the reason? is it because it thinks its impossible to deduce the actual type for `TBody`? or what?

Comment: I don't agree. By declaring the template as "template<typename TArg, typename TBody>", you force the compiler to resolve both template arguments in one go. As for the reasons of not allowing this kind of template resolution, I can only speculate as I wasn't on the standard body.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that the compiler cannot possibly do with the code that you provide, the first of which is deduce the second template argument `TBody`. First, type deduction is only applied to the arguments of the function when the compiler is trying to match the call. At that point the definition of the templated function is not even looked at.

For extra credits, even if the compiler were to look the function definition, the code `TBody v = parameter.member` is non-deducible in itself, as there are potentially infinite data types that can accept a `parameter.member` in the constructor.

Now, on the second block of code. To understand it the whole process of template compilation starts when the compiler sees the function call `g(x)` at that point of call. The compiler sees that the best candidate is the template function `template <typename T> void g( T )` and determines what the type `T` is as part of the overload resolution. Once the compiler determines that it is a call to the template, it performs the first pass of compilation on that function.

During the first pass, syntactic checks are perform without an actual substitution of the type, so the template argument `T` is still *any-type* and the argument `p` is of a yet-unknown type. During the first pass, the code is verified, but *dependent* names are skipped and their meaning is just assumed. When the compiler sees `p.member`, and `p` is of type `T` that is a template argument it assumes that it will be a member of the yet unknown type (this is the reason why if it is a type you would have to qualify it here with `typename`). The call `h(p.member);` is also dependent on the type argument `T` and is left as it is, assuming that once the type substitution takes place everything will make sense.

Then the compiler does actually substitute the type. At this step `T` is no longer a *generic* type, but it represents the concrete type `sample`. Now the compiler during the second pass tries to fill in the gaps that were left during the first pass. When it sees `p.member` it looks `member` inside the type and determines that it is an `int` and tries to resolve the call `h( p.member );` with that knowledge. Because the type `T` has been resolved before this second stage, this is equivalent to the outside call `g(x)`: all types are known and the compiler only needs to resolve what is the best overload for a function call `h` that takes an argument of type `int&`, and the whole process starts again, the template `h` is found as the best candidate, and ...

It is really important for metaprogramming to understand that type deduction is performed only on the actual signature of the function and not the body, and that is what makes it non-trivial for beginners. Using `enable_if` (from boost or elsewhere) in the function signature as argument or return type is not a coincidence, but the only way of having the compiler fail to substitute the type *before* the template is selected as best candidate and the substitution failure is turned into an actual error (and not SFINAE)

Answer (score 0):

No compiler could possibly implement this functionality in a consistent manner. You are simply asking too much.

Comment: could you please elaborate that?

Answer (score 0):

`TBody` might be ambiguous, because `sample` might not be the only type that has a `member` member. Furthermore, if `g` calls other template functions, the compiler has no way of knowing what other restrictions might be imposed on `TBody`.

So in some edge cases, it is theoretically possible to deduce the proper type for `TBody`, generally it is not.